# How DatabaseReference#push() method differs from location to location?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, mbaas

When using Firebase Database I can generate a key using `push()` method of a `DatabaseReference` object as shown in the code snippets below:

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/location").push().getKey();`

or

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey();`

Is there a difference in the above usage?

Please note that I am concerned about the key only, not the returned `DatabaseReference` from `push`

Does `push` method introduce side effects on my online Firebase Database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `push()` method is a pure client-side operation that generates a key that is both chronologically, lexicographically ordered and statistically guaranteed to be unique.

There is (currently) no difference between calling `push()` on one location or another. The method to generate the keys is the exact same and does not depend on the location.

For more on Firebase push ID, I recommend reading the blog post [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).